# QTP: Duplicate function Name in Function Library

Tags: vbscript, qtp

In a QTP project, there are more than 100 function library and some functions are duplicate in these libraries. is there any way to find out these functions name and remove them through QTP or VB script.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no built-in mechanism in QTP/UFT to remove duplicate function names. But if you have your function written in external '.vbs' file, then you can use any advance editor to remove duplicate function name.  Its easy with Notepad++ to find a particular string in all files present in a same folder. You should search function name in all vbs file [[You can use find in files function]](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-use-the-find-in-files-feature-in-notepad.html#gref) and then just delete redundant functions.